# Model save method data check not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am hitting a blank, maybe you can help me steer in the right direction.

Model method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = Contract.objects.filter(rented = self.rented).exclude(id=self.id)
        check_data = gatekeeper_check(self, query)
        if check_data:
            super(Contract, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Function:

```
def gatekeeper_check(self, query):
    current_contracts = {}
    for item in query:
        print(item)
        if (item.agreement_ends >= self.agreement_starts):
            current_contracts[item.id] = f'{item.agreement_starts} - {item.agreement_ends}'
            print(item.agreement_ends, item.actual_agreement_end, self.agreement_starts)
            raise ValidationError(mark_safe(f'Rentable already booked for the date range: <br>' + '<br>'.join({f'Contract ID: {k} | Start-End Date: {v}' for k, v in current_contracts.items()})))
        else:
            return True
```

The result is not what i expect:

`Rentable already booked for the date range:
Contract ID: 6UOj2RnNDX6jiGlC | Start-End Date: 2019-09-30 - 2019-10-29`

On the current object:

start_date: 2019-01-29

end_date:  2019-04-29

This should save ideally because the rentable is not booked on these days. It is however booked from 2019-09-30

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You always return in the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I guess all i needed was an extra pair of eyes. :D